# How can I better store my server credentials for use in Python deployment scripts?

Tags: python, security, credentials

Basically there are a bunch server deployment scripts which reference server credentials (e.g. username, password).  Currently, the credentials are stored in a *servers* dictionary inside their own python module named **server_info**:

```
servers = {
        'dev_server':{'server':'localhost', 'port':'80', 'username':'*********','password' : '*******'},
        'staging_server':{'server':'www.google.com', 'port':'80', 'username':'********','password' : '***********'},
    }
```

The deploy scripts import this module and reference credentials by key:

```
from server_info import servers 

server_creds = servers['dev_server']
update_server(server_creds['username'], server_creds['password'], server_creds['port'])

server_creds = servers['staging_server']
update_server(server_creds['username'], server_creds['password'], server_creds['port'])
```

The separate module prevents having plain-text credentials in the deployment scripts, but there are still in plain-text within the server_info module.

Any advice on how to better store this sensitive information would be appreciated. All ideas are welcome, but looking for platform agnostic solutions.

Comment: Where are you storing `server_info`? Is it outside of your web root in a non-public path?

Comment: yes, non-public path on the hard drive and not commit to source control.

Answer (score -1):

(reversibly) encode it somehow so that it is no longer plaintext... some simple examples are rot13 , base64, ceasar ciphers,  **keep in mind these are really encodings and not encryptions and anyone who has enough inclination to do so can break them**.... even if you use actual encryption you will need to have a key stored in plaintext somewhere (although the key could be entered by the user as a "universal" password or something)

often something as simple as

```
 old_data = open("server_info.py").read()
 open("server_info_encoded.py","w").write(base64.b64encode(old_data))
```

then at some point you pull it in decode it and interpret it as a json dictionary

```
server_info = json.loads(base64.b64decode(open("server_info_encoded.py").read()))
```